# PyInstaller ImportErrror

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Cuando intento hacer un onefile con pyinstaller la consola suelta este Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\users\sebastian manassero\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
File "c:\users\sebastian manassero\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
[250400] Failed to execute script main
```

Estoy perdido, ya que nunca use pyinstaller, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Funciona sin `--onefile`? Probablemente puedes resolver el problema creando un *virtualenv*, y también es posible que el ejecutable no esté encontrando algún recurso. Añade el código del *script principal* de la aplicación por favor.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con su problema, el problema se puede generar a partir de muchas formas. En mi caso cuando intentaba convertir archivos *.py o archivos en general Python, la consola mostraba el mismo error. Algunos de los problemas son los siguientes:

- Los archivos o módulos dependientes de Pyinstaller están corruptos o dañados.
- El sistema propio tiene archivos corruptos o de error de ejecución de imagen.
- La ruta de los archivos fue movida o algunos archivos fueron eliminados
- Su código tiene errores, falta de módulos o falta de archivos que no especificó como iconos comúnmente o no especificó la ruta de los mismos.

La única solución que tuve si no me funcionaba otra solución fue reinstalar Python en general debido a módulos incorrectos y archivos corruptos y de igual forma Pyinstaller. Le recomiendo que al momento de convertirlo a *.exe asegúrese de especificar los archivos (ruta completa), imágenes o iconos, entre otros que hacen parte de su programa.